# How to validate options during startup and on change using custom validators ( FluentValidation)?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using .Net 7 and created a new Web API project. I want to configure my options and validate them using Fluent Validation. Given this example

```
public sealed class LoggingOptions
{
    public const string SectionName = "Logging";
    
    public LogLevel LogLevel { get; init; } = LogLevel.Information;
}

public sealed class LoggingOptionsValidator : AbstractValidator<LoggingOptions>
{
    public LoggingOptionsValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(options => options.LogLevel).IsInEnum();
    }
}
```

So my program.cs looks like

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<LoggingOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(LoggingOptions.SectionName));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<LoggingOptions>, LoggingOptionsValidator>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<LoggingOptions>>().OnChange(options =>
{
     var validator = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IValidator<LoggingOptions>>();
     var validationResult = validator.Validate(options);

     if (!validationResult.IsValid)
     {
         var validationErrors = validationResult.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage);
         throw new OptionsValidationException(nameof(LoggingOptions), typeof(LoggingOptions), validationErrors);
     }
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

This example works fine but it does not validate the options during startup. I want to validate my configuration on startup and on change. I wasn't able to find a similiar hook to `OnChange`, e.g. `OnInit`. So instead I tried to use this exmaple code

```
builder
    .Services
    .AddOptions<LoggingOptions>()
    .Validate(options =>
    {
        var validator = ???; // How do I get the validator?
        var validationResult = validator.Validate(options);

        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            var validationErrors = validationResult.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage);
            throw new OptionsValidationException(nameof(LoggingOptions), typeof(LoggingOptions), validationErrors);
        }
        
        return true;
    })
    .ValidateOnStart()
    .PostConfigure(options =>
    {
        var validator = ???; // How do I get the validator?
        var validationResult = validator.Validate(options);

        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            var validationErrors = validationResult.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage);
            throw new OptionsValidationException(nameof(LoggingOptions), typeof(LoggingOptions), validationErrors);
        }
    });
```

but how do I get an instance of `IValidator<LoggingOptions>`? Not sure if I should use `builder.Build().Services.GetRequiredService<IValidator<LoggingOptions>>()` because why should I build it again?

How would you validate the options during startup?

Comment: *This example works fine but it does not validate the options during startup.* How about initializing with an empty logging configuration and applying the true set later to get the OnChange event fired?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do similar implementation as [ValidateDataAnnotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsbuilderdataannotationsextensions.validatedataannotations?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).
This answer has been created based on [Andrew's Lock article](https://andrewlock.net/adding-validation-to-strongly-typed-configuration-objects-using-flentvalidation/) and [Nick's Chapsas
video about IOptions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jblRYDMTtvg).

First create extension method **ValidateFluently**:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public static class OptionsBuilderFluentValidationExtensions
{
    public static OptionsBuilder<TOptions> ValidateFluently<TOptions>(
      this OptionsBuilder<TOptions> optionsBuilder) where TOptions : class
    {
        optionsBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<TOptions>>(
            provider => new FluentValidationOptions<TOptions>(
              optionsBuilder.Name, provider));
        return optionsBuilder;
    }
}
```

Create implementation for IValidateOptions:

```cs
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.Results;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class FluentValidationOptions<TOptions>
    : IValidateOptions<TOptions> where TOptions : class
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly string? _name;
    public FluentValidationOptions(string? name, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // we need the service provider to create a scope later
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _name = name; // Handle named options
    }

    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string? name, TOptions options)
    {
        // Null name is used to configure all named options.
        if (_name != null && _name != name)
        {
            // Ignored if not validating this instance.
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Skip;
        }

        // Ensure options are provided to validate against
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(options);

        // Validators are typically registered as scoped,
        // so we need to create a scope to be safe, as this
        // method is be called from the root scope
        using IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

        // retrieve an instance of the validator
        var validator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IValidator<TOptions>>();

        // Run the validation
        ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(options);
        if (results.IsValid)
        {
            // All good!
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
        }

        // Validation failed, so build the error message
        string typeName = options.GetType().Name;
        var errors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var result in results.Errors)
        {
            errors.Add($"Fluent validation failed for '{typeName}.{result.PropertyName}' with the error: '{result.ErrorMessage}'.");
        }

        return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(errors);
    }
}
```

Register Fluent Validators for LoggingOptions:

```cs
builder.Services.AddOptions<LoggingOptions>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(LoggingOptions.SectionName))
    .ValidateFluently()
    .ValidateOnStart();
```

After that the validation on start up is working.
[image]

Validation is also working when the options has been modified.
Here is simple controller which returns the options.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class LoggingOptionsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get([FromServices] IOptionsMonitor<LoggingOptions> optionsMonitor)
            => Ok(optionsMonitor.CurrentValue);
    }
}
```

appSettings.Development.json

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": "Debug"
  }
}
```

// GET https://localhost:7196/loggingoptions 200 -> {"logLevel":1}

appSettings.Development.json

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": "hello world"
  }
}
```

// GET https://localhost:7196/loggingoptions 500 -> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to convert configuration value at 'Logging:LogLevel' to type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel'.
---> System.FormatException: hello world is not a valid value for LogLevel.